# What is the correct order of Relative Inductive Effect (-I) of different groups?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inductive-effect

This confusion has put me in problem several times since last 2 years and I have been looking for a clarification but it seems that answer depends upon who you ask. I have several examples where I have searched and infact I changed my chemistry teacher to get this one right but again I am not sure which teacher is correct. We have two orders of Inductive effect from my two different teachers and backed by several websites but I don't know which one is correct.

Let's see the orders

For -I

From Teacher A

[image: -I inductive effect order]

I am typing -I inductive effect from teacher A here for indexation as stated in comments

$$\ce{NF3+} >\ce{NR3+} >\ce{NH3+} >\ce{SR2+} >\ce{NO2}  >\ce{CN} >\\
>\ce{SO3H} >\ce{CHO} >\ce{CO} >\ce{COOH} >\ce{COCl} >\ce{COOR} >\\
>\ce{CONH2}  >\ce{F} >\ce{Cl} >\ce{Br} >\ce{I} >\ce{OH} >\ce{OR}$$

From Teacher B
[image: -I inductive effect order]

I am typing -I inductive effect from teacher B here for indexation as stated in comments

$$\ce{NR3+} > \ce{NF3+} > \ce{SR2+} > \ce{NH3+}  > \ce{NO2} >\\
>\ce{SO2R}  >\ce{CN} > \ce{SO2Ar}  >\ce{COOH} >\ce{F} >\ce{Cl} >\\
>\ce{Br}  >\ce{I} >\ce{OAr} >\ce{COOR} >\ce{OR}  >\ce{COR} >\\
>\ce{SH} >\ce{SR} >\ce{OH} >\ce{CCR} (\mathrm{alkyne}) >\ce{Ar} >\ce{CHCR2} (\mathrm{alkene})$$
Where Ar = Aromatic

There are several websites which have different orders too

Please refer -I effect order on following websites and see how they are different from each other

https://www.vedantu.com/iit-jee/inductive-effect

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_effect

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-order-of-I-and-I-effect

Notice how some keep $ \ce{COOH} $ ahead of $\ce{CO}$ and vice versa, also notice that how some keep $ \ce{NR3+} $ahead of $\ce{NF3+}$ and vice versa although I know for this one that$\ce{ NR3+ }$has more -I effect. Please correct me if I am wrong.

And trust me, I have been trying for an answer for very long time but I didn't found an answer which is from an authentic source. Please consider my desperation for the answer before downvoting as I am going to appear for IIT JEE exam within few months. Thankyou to anyone who tries to answer this question.

Comment: Note that using photos/screenshots of text instead of typing text itself is highly discouraged.  The image text content cannot be indexed nor searched for, nor can be reused in answers.  Specifically handwritten scripts can be difficult to decipher.  Consider  copy/pasting or rewriting of at least essential parts. 

Suitable formatting can be done according to [formatting math/chem expressions/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).

Comment: @Poutnik I have put the order in the text as expected, thank you

Comment: As resources, see also [chem.libretexts.org - Bookshelves - Organic_Chemistry](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry) and [CH SE: chemistry resources](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry)